# Make the flag dialog in Discussions draggable

Tags: feature-request, design, discussions-space, flag-dialog

Currently, if you open the flag dialog in a Discussion and want to see something in the post that is behind it, you have to close it then reopen it.

Make the flag dialog draggable like it is in the rest of the site.